# How to prevent power transfer (reverse current) between two DE-9 RS-232 cables?

Tags: usb, serial, rs232, usb-pd

we have two USB host devices that communicate with each other and as part of the chain, we are using two Serial to USB cables to connect them, like this:

[image]

We are not 100% sure as this happened at a remote site and we cannot reproduce it in our office, but we believe we experienced an instance of power backflow / reverse current where one of the host devices shut off when plugged into the setup (the other host device is simultaneously being charged by a wall charger).

If we wanted to eliminate the possibility of any reverse current in this setup, what is the best way to achieve this?

Possible ideas we are hoping for feedback on:

- Wire a custom DE-9 cable in between the two Serial to USB cables with only TX, RX and GND
- RS-232 optical isolator in between the two Serial to USB cables
- USB isolation device at the USB end of the second host device

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB-serial adapters typically have output-only level conversion, and wide-voltage-tolerant inputs, i.e. backflow *per se* is not possible.  That leaves some kind of grounding issue, which should be verifiable by measuring the DC and AC voltage between ground/shield at either end.  This in turn suggests an isolator, of which any method will do, RS-232 or USB.

Which further suggests a wiring fault on the site, which indeed would not be reproducible in the office.

The charger may be a *non sequitur*, or it may be faulty.

Comment: Your idea that a typical USB to RS-232 adapter does not have receive level conversion does not match mine. Which cables are typical, and which don't have input level conversion?

Comment: Hah, that does read a bit ambiguous.  I mean the level conversion, for outputs, is output-only, it doesn't receive or backflow power.

Answer (score 3):

There is not (normally) any power feed in a DE-9 RS-232 connection, so there should be no possibility of a power backfeed through the cable, unless there is a difference in "Ground" voltages beween the devices.

When I make an RS-232 cable, I only connect RX, TX and GND - the handshaking signals are rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

I second the hypothesis of a *relevant* ground differential.

Some power adapters can have a faulty to high leakage current from mains to secondary. Checking the leakage from the *GND* terminal to the protective earth is one step.

Another method I'd try, even though it could be palliative, is rotating the mains plug 180 degrees - i.e. *exchanging the two mains terminals* on the adapter.
Maybe the internal capacitor routed from DC power GND to a mains terminal will have that 50% chance to go to neutral... hence reducing that leakage :D

You can even route GND to PE yourself... if the adapter is failing hopefully a GFCI will trigger!

Sure enough, a good adapter, with a PE terminal and GND routed to it, would be a safe choice.